# Grails Error "violates foreign key constraint" unable to add an Object while trying to save multiple objects at one time

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am trying to save Domain class objects which are mapped like-

```
class Order {
   String prefix
   Long orderNumber
   Date date
   Incident incident
   //..... few more variables
}

class Incident {
    Double amountToCharge
    String description
    Boolean isCharged = false
    Order order
    //..... few more variables
}
```

Now when I am trying to save them inside my service class I do the following-

```
def save(Order orderInstance, params){
    orderInstance.withTransaction { status ->

          if (orderInstance.save()) {

            if(params.isIncident){
                def incidentStatus = saveIncident(params, orderInstance)

                if(incidentStatus.result == true){
                    println "-----------------Incident Saved"
                }else{
                    status.setRollbackOnly()
                    result["result"] = false
                    result["message"] = "Could not save. Please try again."
                    return result
                }
            }

            result["result"] = true

            return result
        } else {

            for (fieldErrors in orderInstance.errors) {
                for (error in fieldErrors.allErrors) {
                    result["message"] = messageSource.getMessage(error, locale)
                }
            }
            return result
        }
    }
}

def saveIncident(params, Order orderInstance){
    def result = [:]

    def paramsMap = [:]
    paramsMap.description = params.incident.description
    paramsMap.amountToCharge = params.incident.amountToCharge
    paramsMap.isCharged = params.incident.isCharged ? false : true
    paramsMap.order = mROrderInstance

    def incidentInstance = new Incident(paramsMap)
    println "-----Done till here. Next line throws error----"
    if (incidentInstance.save(flush:true)){
        orderInstance.incident = incidentInstance

        result["result"] = true
    }else{
        result["result"] = false

        for (fieldErrors in incidentInstance.errors) {
            for (error in fieldErrors.allErrors) {
                println messageSource.getMessage(error, locale)
                result["message"] = messageSource.getMessage(error, locale)
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

It gives me the following error-

```
ERROR: insert or update on table "order" violates foreign key     constraint "fk_a0y0jvv0o9nhkafuj7g7iknc6"
Detail: Key (incident_id)=(2) is not present in table "incident".. Stacktrace follows:
Message: ERROR: insert or update on table "order" violates foreign key constraint "fk_a0y0jvv0o9nhkafuj7g7iknc6"
Detail: Key (incident_id)=(2) is not present in table "incident".
Line | Method
->> 2102 | receiveErrorResponse in org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1835 | processResults       in     ''
|    257 | execute . . . . . .  in     ''
|    500 | execute              in    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement
|    388 | executeWithFlags . . in     ''
|    334 | executeUpdate        in     ''
|    124 | $tt__saveIncident .  in com.xyz.fleet.db.OrderService$$EPZ0qsAS
|     46 | doCall               in com.xyz.fleet.db.OrderService$_$tt__save_closure6$$EPZ0qsAS
|    815 | withTransaction . .  in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi
|    715 | withTransaction      in     ''
|     41 | $tt__save . . . . .  in com.xyz.fleet.db.MROrderService$$EPZ0qsAS
|     32 | $tt__save            in com.xyz.fleet.db.MROrderController
|    198 | doFilter . . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter             in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter . . . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter             in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter . . . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     46 | doFilterInternal     in org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter
|   1142 | runWorker . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run                  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

The error comes when I flush the session. Even if I dont then whenever it automatically flushes then it throws the same error.

Note: In case I don't flush the session manually then the `Incident` is saved, the method returns back to save `Order`. It saves that as well. The `Incident` object is attached to Order object which I can check using `println` 
But at the end when it automatically clears the session then the same error is thrown which is shown above.

So finally can anyone tell me what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that `Order.incident` is not nullable (the default) and you're trying to save the **order** without saving it's `Incident` first.

```
def order = ...
def incident = ...

if(incident.save()) {
    order.incident = incident
    order.save()
}
```

If an instance of `Incident` can belong to only a single `Order`, try adding `belongsTo`:

```
class Incident {
    Double amountToCharge
    String description
    Boolean isCharged = false
    Order order
    //..... few more variables

    static belongsTo = [order: Order]
}
```

The bi-directional many-to-one association simplifies saving instances.

```
def order = ...
def incident = ...

order.incident = incident
order.save()
```

The bi-directional many-to-one association causes the `Order` and `Incident` to get saved together.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. No actually it is not the case of nullable instead I am creating the `Incident` object and `Order` object and attaching them. But when the hibernate session flushes then PostgreSQL throws an error that (incident_id)=(2) is not present in table "incident". Definately I'll try adding a mapping to them.

Comment: Well, if you're not using `belongsTo` them make sure you save the `Incident` before you save the `Order`. You can *attach* them ahead of time, but the save order is important.